# Can get final CNF formula from Z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

Here is my simple encoding. I would like to get the final Boolean CNF that presents all these constrains. Is there any option in Z3 solver to get the final Boolean CNF ?

```
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')

c1 = And(x >= 1, x <= 10)
c2 = And(y >= 1, y <= 10)
c3 = Distinct(x,y)

s = Solver()
s.add(c1 , c2 , c3)
# I need the final Boolean CNF formula from Z3 solver...
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992531/convert-formula-to-cnf, use goals and tactics, there should be examples in `examples` folder of Z3.

Answer (score 3):

As Ayrat says, use goals and tactics. 
Here is an example: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/4I3

```
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')

c1 = And(x >= 1, x <= 10)
c2 = And(y >= 1, y <= 10)
c3 = Distinct(x,y)

g = Goal()
g.add(c1 , c2 , c3)

describe_tactics()

t = Tactic('tseitin-cnf')
print t(g)
```