# How to get every clauses of a CNF formula in Z3

Tags: z3, boolean-logic

like in the code below, Is there any function in Z3 to get all the clauses of a formula(as a CNF)?

```
x = Boolean('x')
y = Boolean('y')

f = And(x, Or(x,y),And(x,Not(x,y))
# can I get all the clauses of formula f stored in a list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
from z3 import *

x = Bool('x')    #  Note: Bool() rather than Boolean()
y = Bool('y')
z = Bool('z')

f = And(x, Or(x,y), And(x, z == Not(y)))

#  from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003288/1911064

g = Goal()
g.add(f)
    
# use describe_tactics() to get to know the tactics available

t = Tactic('tseitin-cnf')
clauses = t(g)

for clause in clauses[0]:
    print(clause)
```

Output is a list of disjunctive clauses:

```
x
Or(x, y)
Or(y, z)
Or(Not(y), Not(z))
```

Your original expression is not satisfiable.

What is `Not(x, y)` supposed to do?

As simpler way to convert (nested) Boolean expressions to *CNF* is provided by [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/).

Comment: Sry, I originally want to show "Or(x,y)", and thanks a lot!